# Meteor 0.6.5 - Utterly basic example with accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown not working

Tags: meteor

Here is my project structure:

```
├── app.html
├── app.js
├── packages/
│   └── accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown -> /Users/jon/.meteorite/packages/accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown/erobit/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown/c8b29d2e7f8611d6dec9d6d23c1c2b94e000b0fb/
├── smart.json
└── smart.lock
```

`meteor list --using' gives the following result:

```
standard-app-packages
autopublish
insecure
preserve-inputs
accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown
bootstrap
accounts-password
```

app.html is as follows:

```
<head>
  <title>app</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> header}}
</body>

<template name="header">
    <header class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul>
                    <li>{{loginButtons}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>
```

app.js is as follows:

```
Accounts.ui.config({ passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL' });
```

I get the following error when I try to launch the app:

```
[[[[[ ~/dev/app ]]]]]

=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/
W202309-16:30:21.275(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/jon/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W202309-16:30:21.365(-4)? (STDERR)                      throw(ex);
W202309-16:30:21.365(-4)? (STDERR)                            ^
W202309-16:30:21.366(-4)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'config' of undefined
W202309-16:30:21.366(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/app.js:1:48
W202309-16:30:21.366(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/app.js:24:3
W202309-16:30:21.367(-4)? (STDERR)     at mains (/Users/jon/dev/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:153:10)
W202309-16:30:21.367(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W202309-16:30:21.367(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/jon/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W202309-16:30:21.367(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/jon/dev/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:80:5
=> Exited with code: 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accounts.ui.config is only available on the client (see documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_ui_config)), so you need to wrap its use in Meteor.isClient.  Replacing your app.js with this should work:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
  Accounts.ui.config({ passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_OPTIONAL_EMAIL' });
}
```

Alternately, you can create a folder called "client" and a folder called "server", and Meteor will know how to deal with those without using isClient and isServer.

For more information, see "[structuring your app](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp)" in the documentation or "where should I put my files?" in the [unofficial faq](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I hadn't added accounts-base and accounts-ui. I had just added the accounts-[service] packages. Once I added them, the error went away and all was fine.